# Improve calculating time for show several different result from a research

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image]

The aim of this sheet is to show every results (even if it's different) in range D:D from the spreadsheet in A1:B11 with the accurate city in D1.

This is my formula in D2 :

```
=SIERREUR(INDEX(B:B;PETITE.VALEUR(SI(ESTNUM(EQUIV(A:A;$D$1;0));EQUIV(LIGNE(A:A);LIGNE(A:A));"");LIGNES(($A$1:A1))));"")
```

It works well, BUT, when I extend this formula to a lot of data, my workbook become very very slow (such slow that I can not move toward the sheet and even select cells).
I needed to put the calculating method to "Manual" for change the sheet.

Any ideas to get the same result but with a different method/way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the very latest version, with the `FILTER` function, (and with your city/rank information in a **Table**) you can use:

```
=FILTER(Table7[rank],Table7[City]=$D$1)
```

To sort ascending, you can use the new `SORT` function:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Table7[rank],Table7[City]=$D$1))
```

For those with older versions of Excel, but with the `AGGREGATE` function (*which I think appeared in 2010 (possibly 2007)*), you can use

```
Unsorted:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Table7[rank],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table7[City]=$D$1)*(ROW(Table7)-ROW(Table1[#Headers])),ROWS($1:1))),"")

Sorted:  =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table7[City]=$D$1)*Table7[rank],ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing function ! It works, and if I want to class the result by ascending ?

Comment: Ty ! And do you think there is a way to show another column that correspond to that SORT/FILTER ? For exemple, if the rank "2" corredpond to Paris AND another city like "Oslo". So the result dont change with our case. But if we want to show to what rank corespond in the column E ? Excel will hesitate between Oslo or Paris. Do we have a solution to show only Paris because there is Paris in D1 ?

Comment: @Bitoku I think that is worthy of a separate question with appropriate examples, desired outputs and what you've tried. I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for from your comment and that can be laid out much more clearly in a full question.